# WiFi not recognized on Arch Linux - was working on Windows 10

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, iwd

I have a Laptop with Arch Linux.

No wifi adapter is showing up in `iwd`. It does not recognize it exists, although WiFi worked while on Windows 10. I also have no access to other things.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to include the model of your WiFi adapter, and the output of `lspci`.

Comment: Also clarify if this is a laptop, a desktop, what kind of interface the adaptor is using (PCI? USB? Something else?). We need to know what hardware you are using. Finally, have you followed [the instructions on the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration/Wireless) to set it up?

Comment: Did you check the output of `dmesg` and see if your NIC is being seen at all?